# How to update line chart points when the source data changes

Tags: d3.js

I've created a multi-line chart from the following source data.

```
[   
    {
      "key":"108",
      "title":"Series 1",
      "items":[
        {
          "key":"54048872e9c2021fd8231051",
          "value":1.0
        },
        {
          "key":"540488a1e9c2021fd823107b",
          "value":2.0
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "key":"15",
      "title":"Series 2",
      "items":[
        {
          "key":"54048872e9c2021fd8231051",
          "value":1.0
        },
        {
          "key":"540488a1e9c2021fd823107b",
          "value":4.0
        }
      ]
    }
]
```

We render a line for each `Series` and circles for each data "point"

```
    var series = svg.selectAll('.series')
        .data(this.data)
        .enter()
            .append('g')
            .attr('class', 'series');

    series.append('path')
        .attr('class', 'line');

    // add points to chart
    var points = series.append('g')
        .attr('class', 'point')
        .selectAll('circle')
        .data(function (d) {
            return d.items;
        })
        .enter()
        .append('circle')
        .attr('r', 5);
```

Then when we first render the chart or when the window resizes we actually set the coordinates of the line and circles:

```
    this.svg.selectAll('.line')
        .attr('d', function (d) {
            return chart.line(d.items);
        });

    this.svg.selectAll('.point circle')
     .attr('cx', function (d) { return chart.xScale(d.key); })
     .attr('cy', function (d) { return chart.yScale(d.value); });
```

Here, `chart.line` corresponds to a d3 line generator previously created.

When the source data changes I can update the line by setting its data:

```
    this.svg.selectAll('.line')
        .data(this.data);
```

But I can't figure out how to do the same thing with the data points (circles).

I've tried the following but the data on the individual point is not actually updated. Here the first console log (after selecting the `.point` elements) returns the correct data but the `cx` attribute function is returning the old data.

```
    var series = this.svg.selectAll('.series')
            .data(this.data)
            .selectAll('.point')
                .data(function (d) {
                    console.log(d.items);
                    return d.items;
                })
                .selectAll('circle')
                .attr('class', 'updated')
                .attr('cx', function (d) { console.log(d); return chart.xScale(d.key); })
                .attr('cy', function (d) { return chart.yScale(d.value); });
```

Comment: Could you post a JSfiddle for this?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this issue?. I'm having the same one, it seems you can empty the SVG element with `$('#chart svg').empty()` whenever you change the date, but that makes you lose the fancy 'reloading data' animation and I'd like to keep it.

Comment: I know this is a relatively old question but I was having a similar issue so I threw together a quick JSFiddle for this -- http://jsfiddle.net/Lmqwkudb/2/  I can't duplicate the issue for this question with this.  One thing that stands out is that the data bind on the update is being performed on the .point selection rather than the circle selection but this doesn't break things with my JSFiddle.